# How to traverse a nested key value pair object in JUEL(Java Unified Expression Language) & return a certain index to evaluate against?

Tags: json, nested-loops, key-value, nested-lists, juel

I have an object with duplicate key value pairs. I need to traverse it & evaluate **index [0] only** against a condition:

```
var cells = {"cells": [{"key": "-18", "key1": "-9", "key2": "-51", "key3": "23"}, {"key": 
"-18", "key1": "-9", "key2": "-51", "key3": "23"}, {"key": "-18", "key1": "-9", "key2": "-51", 
"key3": "23"}]};
```

My code so far:

```
var result = true;

if (cells instanceof java.util.List && !cells.isEmpty()) {
 for (var i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
    var cell = cells.get(i);

    var key = cell.get("key");
    var primeKey = key.get[0];
    if (primeKey) {
        if (parseInt(primeKey) < 5) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
} else {
result = false;
}

return result;
```

The error that I get is:
Error encountered during evaluation: TypeError: Cannot read property "0.0" from undefined
(#12)

Comment: _"I have a nested JSON object"_ - No. That's an object with one property which is an array of objects -> [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131)

Comment: `java.util.List` is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: This looks like a mix of java and javascript…

Comment: That `.size()` looks more like Java then JavaScript

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is a Java Interface: The Java List interface, java. util. List , represents an ordered sequence of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var primeKey = key.get[0];` is nonsensical as the `"key"` value pair is not an array to be iterated. However, if we simply change the `i` iterator to index `0` like so  `var cell = cells.get(0);` we can evaluate the condition against index `0` only. No need to traverse the entire nested loop as we are only comparing against index `0`. See below for details:

```
var cells = {"cells": [{"key": "-18", "key1": "-9", "key2": "-51", "key3": "23"}, {"key": 
"-18", "key1": "-9", "key2": "-51", "key3": "23"}, {"key": "-18", "key1": "-9", "key2": "-51", 
"key3": "23"}]};

var result = true;

if (cells instanceof java.util.List && !cells.isEmpty()) {
 for (var i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
    var cell = cells.get(0);

    var key = cell.get("key");
    if (primeKey) {
        if (parseInt(primeKey) < 5) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
} else {
result = false;
}

return result;
```